# Angular Service Factory pattern

Tags: angular, design-patterns, service, factory, provider

I am trying to deploy a new module for work and I am stuck on how to implement the design pattern for my service.

To be specific I have a generic class called 'LoggerService' which gets extended by my services for console logging and database logging. 
I now want to be able to export the whole module and fetch it from a proxy within the company. 
The publishing and fetching works, but now the problem is that when I want to instantiate either one of the concrete services, angular tells me that this service was not exported. 
`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [NgxCmLoggerComponent],
  imports: [NgxCmHttpModule
  ],
  exports: [NgxCmLoggerComponent],
  providers: [NgxCmDatabaseLoggerService, NgxCmConsoleLoggerService]
})
export class NgxCmLoggerModule { 
  static forRoot(config: NgxCmLoggerService): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: NgxCmLoggerModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: NgxCmLoggerService, useClass: config}
      ]
    };
  }
}`
```

This is how my module looks like, as you can see I am providing both Services and I have the forRoot method to instantiate the service I want for the use case. 
`

```
NgxCmLoggerModule.forRoot(new NgxCmConsoleLoggerService),
```

`
That's how I am trying to instantiate my service, in this case, the console logger. When I try this, angular signals me that the ConsoleLoggerService, which should be provided by the module, is not available. 
I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong with respect to the forRoot method, I just don't know what.

I am happy for any help,
thank you,
Chris.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I have found the solution to my problem, which was sadly easier than thought. I simply missed the configuration of my public-api typescript file. Without telling my module's public interface that it is allowed to publish the other logging classes as well, it will of course not do that. 
So maybe it helps some of you, who also failed to see the wood for the trees.